# Linq query to orderby

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

My database has 3 tables. All I want to do is order it by the most recent Date in Table 3

The tables look a little like

Table1

```
ID    CompanyId
1       1
2       1
3       2
```

Table2

```
Id    CompanyColumn
1      Blah
2      Bleh
```

Table3

```
Id    CompanyId    Date
1       1          5/1/2015
2       1          8/1/2015
3       1          15/1/2015
4       2          6/1/2015
```

I am using EF and my object is based upon Table1

So, I can do

```
var tab1 = this.Entities.Table1;//I now have a reference to table 1


var result = from t in tab1
             group t by d.Table2.Table3.Select(a => a.Date)
             into g
             select g.FirstOrDefault();
```

Error message is

> The key selector type for the call to the 'GroupBy' method is not comparable in the underlying store provider.

I tried

```
var result = from t in tab1
             group t by d.CompanyId
             into g
             select g.FirstOrDefault();

result = result.OrderByDescending(a => a.Table2.Table3.Select(b => b.DateTime));
```

Error message is

> DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable.\r\nParameter name: key

I'm totally lost

Comment: You should tell us the molteplicity of the various relations: are they 1:1, 1:many, many:1, many:many . It changes how the query can be built

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this

```
d.Table2.Table3.Select(a => a.Date)
```

or this

```
a.Table2.Table3.Select(b => b.DateTime)
```

you get a whole sequence of dates represented by an `IQueryable<Date>` in the first case or `IQueryable<DateTime>` in the second case. You get an error because `IQueryable<T>` is not `IComparable<IQueryable<T>>`.

Essentially, the problem is that each expression produces potentially more than one `Date` or `DateTime`. If you replace `Select` with an aggregate function, such as `Min` or `Max`, the code would compile:

```
var result = from t in tab1
         group t by d.Table2.Table3.Min(a => a.Date)
         into g
         select g.FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
result = result.OrderByDescending(a => a.Table2.Table3.Min(b => b.DateTime));
```